# Convert list items to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this.

```
['February 01,2011 - February 28, 2011', 'March 01,2011 - March 31, 2011']
```

I want to convert it to

```
[('February 01,2011 - February 28, 2011'), ('March 01,2011 - March 31, 2011')]
```

Any Ideas??
Please help!!!
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 13):

To make a tuple with 1 element, append a comma in the parentheses:

```
>>> my_list = ['February 01,2011 - February 28, 2011', 'March 01,2011 - March 31, 2011']
>>> [(x,) for x in my_list]
[('February 01,2011 - February 28, 2011',), ('March 01,2011 - March 31, 2011',)]
```